# What is an HTMLSelectElement and an HTMLInputElement?

Tags: vba

I'm attempting to learn VBA by reading through someone's code and understanding what happens every step of the way. However, I'm confused at to what these two elements are:

What is a HTMLSelectElement?
What is a HTMLInputElement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume they correspond to [select](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_select.asp) and [input](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_input.asp) HTML tags.  A select tag is also called a drop-down list, and input tags can be used for multiple things (checkbox, radio button, text, password).

Answer (score 4):

See the **W3C** [HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/cover.html#minitoc) Specs:

[HTMLSelectElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6)

[HTMLInputElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4)